# Blob Detection OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Typically how much time would it take to capture an image feed from a webcam and detect a blob in it?

Can it be done real time?

I am new to OpenCV, wanted to clarify few things before I jump in to coding.

thanks

Comment: Yes this can be done in real time with e.g. 15frames/sec. But it depends a lot on your image size, type of blob and accurancy that you want to achive.

Comment: In my case, the image size would be the screen resolution. And the blob would be a small illumination on a black image. And can you also tell me if I can locate the position of the blob in the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done in realtime. Check the CMVision library. They've got some blazingly fast code for segmenting an image based on colour.

Answer (score 0):

There a library to work with blob. Works fine and its complementary with OpenCV.
Its name is cvBlob. Search in google the page in googlecode. There are easy examples to know how to use it.

I'm not the creator but i work with it a think its great.

Good Work.